# Uploading cookbook on Chef SuperMarket

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I am trying to upload a cookbook to  Chef Super market , I have taken the keypair from chef.io after creating my login . Here is my knife.rb:

```
current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "readonlychef"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/ishucap1.pem"
validation_client_name   "ishucap1"
validation_key           "#{current_dir}/developer-validator.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://supermarket.chef.io"
cache_type               'BasicFile'
cache_options( :path => "#{ENV['HOME']}/.chef/checksums" )
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/chef/cookbooks/"]
```

While I am running the share command , I am getting the following error :

```
985aeb8b6b92:~ zng937$  knife cookbook site share myfirstcookbook "Other" -o ./chef/cookbooks/ 
Generating metadata for myfirstcookbook from /var/folders/6s/vb0m1sqd1hldg7thk6m3dflmv7dc2h/T/chef-myfirstcookbook-build20150605-6029-ml3e6e/myfirstcookbook/metadata.rb
Making tarball myfirstcookbook.tgz
The environment variable HTTP_PROXY is discouraged.  Use http_proxy.
ERROR: Error uploading cookbook myfirstcookbook to the Opscode Cookbook Site: 407 "Proxy Authentication Required". Increase log verbosity (-VV) for more information.
```

Comment: With the same configuration , I can download the exiting cookbooks :  '985aeb8b6b92:~ zng937$ knife cookbook site download chef-client_syslog
Downloading chef-client_syslog from the cookbooks site at version 0.1.1 to /Users/zng937/chef-client_syslog-0.1.1.tar.gz
Cookbook saved: /Users/zng937/chef-client_syslog-0.1.1.tar.gz
'

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed up `chef_server_url` and `supermarket.chef.io`.

The Chef Server stores and serves all your **internal** resources of your infrastructure, `Supermarket` is the **public** repository for community cookbooks.

Comment: Makes sense, But does the chef_server_url even matters here ?

Comment: I can removed this url just for this purpose and ran the command again , still got the same error.

Comment: Your http proxy requires authentication. Try setting the `http_proxy` variable including credentials. e.g. `export http_proxy=http://user:password@server:port/`

Comment: Actually I had setit up as HTTP_PROXY , but now I have setit up with the lower case as well , but still getting this problem.

Comment: Just to add more info to this question , I have registered as  a individual contributor on the supermarket . This particular sample cookbook , I want to add to just my profile , if not globally . As I am doing it just for my testing.

Comment: Try setting the credentials in your knife.rb, too: https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html#proxy-settings - regarding supermarket: All cookbooks are public.

Comment: tried again , didnt work by setting the cred in knife.rb

Comment: hm. Maybe knife doesnt' support proxy auth. You could give https://github.com/sethvargo/stove a try.